# Using a single metric to track both success and failures in Datadog

Tags: metrics, datadog, observability

Currently our codebase tracks two separate metrics, lets say `a.b.c.success` and `a.b.c.failure`. We always increment the metric by a value of 1 each time.

Is it necessary to separate these metrics? Or can we "increment" the metric by a value of `0` for errors, and `1` for success, and if we wanted a total count of failures, we could subtract the sum in a time period from total count?

I tried to confirm this could work through the metric explorer by looking at graphs for both `sum:a.b.c.success{*}.as_count()` and `count:a.b.c.success{*}.as_count()`. Since I'm always incrementing the value by 1, I would expect these values to be the same but the `count` value is significantly higher (and always in increments of 10 per time slice?)